# How should I break this long Python line?

Tags: python, code-formatting

I'm formatting my code that is going to be included in the appendices of a report, so respecting 80 characters lines is more than a PEP8 fanatism, since if the lines are too long they continue past the width of the paper.

Usually, breaking long lines using PEP8 recommendations and some logic, things are pretty easy, but I encountered this 90 characters long line, which is indented 3 times :

```
            valleys.append(data.index(min(data[frontieres[f*2+1]:frontieres[f*2+2]])))
```

How should I break it, without changing variables name if possible?

Comment: Make intermediate variables? At least one for the `min` value.

Comment: To anyone who wants to edit this question: the indentation is on purpose.

Comment: you're setting a lot of steps into just one. It's obvious that you're going to get such a big line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        data_range = data[frontieres[f*2+1]:frontieres[f*2+2]]
        data_min = min(data_range)
        index_min = data.index(data_min)
        valleys.append(index_min)
```

Obviously you may inline any of introduces variables.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about it initially!

Answer (score 5):

I don't like the idea I advice you that, because good practise would be to rewrite that line into something more readable. However, if you have to for grater good format existing code into scientific report, then here you have my suggestion:

```
valleys.append(
  data.index(
    min(
      data[frontieres[f*2+1]:frontieres[f*2+2]]
)))
```

Python allows to split lines between brackets without any additional trickery.

More correct way would be:

```
valleys.append(
  data.index(
    min(
      data[frontieres[f*2+1]:frontieres[f*2+2]]
    )
  )
)
```

In fact you can split your indexes this way as well.

Comment: Interesting observation. If I compare my multiline variant with rewrites below, I have that feeling the my formatting is actually more readable, than these stuff with multiple variables. Like intentions are clear at first sight.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to break the line.

- Using `\`:
  You can insert it anywhere *(even between variables)* and take that down from there:

  ```
          valleys.append(data.index(min(data[frontieres[f*2+1]\
                        :frontieres[f*2+2]])))
  ```
- Breaking from `(`:
  Any function can take argument on the other line

  ```
          valleys.append(data.index(min(
              data[frontieres[f*2+1]:frontieres[f*2+2]]
          )))
  ```

I prefer the later one for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 2):

**Just use variables:**

```
some_data = data[frontieres[f*2+1]:frontieres[f*2+2]]
min_some_data = min(some_data)
data_index = data.index(min_some_datan)
valleys.append(data_index)
```